# Git clients show already commited changes as "changed"

Tags: git

I have a repository with no changes (everything is commited).
`git status` shows me that the repository is clean.

Unfortunately other git clients (like the build-in version in Atom or GitKraken) marks a lot of files in yellow (changed).

I've generated the project with the ember-cli generators so the local repository (`.git`) including the initial commit was also generated.

When trying to stage the marked files one more time, the "buggy" clients wont do that without any comments.

Im using windows 10 with cygwin64 and git 2.7.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe git is trying to keep track of file modes. You might want to try turning this off.

Comment: It is possible you have a line ending issue. Your command line git may be using a different value for `autocrlf` than your other clients. Have you tried diffing the files to see what is being marked as changed?

Answer (score 0):

As Christoph Sommer mentioned correctly (and thanks to Kevin Burdett I found confirmation in my client), the problem was that in my *.git/config-File* `filemode` was set to `true`.

[image]